# Facebook Likes Same for *every page* (with querystrings)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, addthis

I'm trying to have different pages on the same website (all distinguished by querystrings which load different content) have their own number of likes.

Problem is, they all have the same number of Likes no matter what I do. The opengraph meta tags are different on each page yet somehow Facebook recognises them all as the same page and when one gets likes, the main one (without any query strings) gets the likes.

What could be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write out the like button, are you encoding the "?" correctly? Make sure you are `urlencode()` the whole url param (if you are in PHP).

Put your url in here to see the like button source

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/